# Generate All Permutations of Several Lists in Permutation-Value Order

Tags: python, algorithm

I have looked at several other questions on permutations and this variant does not seem to appear.  I am looking for a simple way to generate a biased permutation.  Here's what I mean.

Suppose I have two lists (though I need to solve for *N* lists):

```
l1 = [a, b, c]
l2 = [d, e, f]
```

Permutations of these lists would look like [(a,d), (a,e), (a,f), (b,d), (b,e), (b,f) ...]. However, in my world the elements of permutations are scored and summed to value the arrangement.  Supposing **a**, **d** and **e** are worth 2 points and **b**, **c** and **f** are worth 1 point. The value of some sample permutations are then:

```
(a,d) = 4
(a,e) = 4 
(a,f) = 3
(c,f) = 2
```

I need to generate all permutations but I would like to generate high value permutations before lower value permutations.

Assuming the elements of each list are sorted in descending value order, is there a nice way to generate the permutations in value-order?

(Obviously I can generate all of the permutations and sort them but I would prefer to write a generator as the number of permutations can be large.)

Comment: why is b before d? Also do you want the product or permutations?

Comment: Should (b, c) really be in the list? My understanding was that you were mixing the two.

Comment: voting to close as it is not very clear what you expect as output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am looking for the permutations. I fixed the example, looks clear now.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus That was a typo, should have been c,f.  The lists are independent, should not mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, lets take l1={6,4,3,1} and l2={5,4,1}. Plot them as horizontal and vertical lines on 2D plane.

[image: Plot and swip line]

Then points of interest are all intersections. We should report those intersections in order an imaginary sweep line moving from (inf, inf) to (0, 0) touches them. Notice that a point lying on the horizontal line can't be reported earlier than another point on the same line which is righter. So for each horizontal line we must check only rightmost point. From all those points, we must choose one with the greatest sum of coordinates. This can be done with heap data structure.

Initially, we place all points lying on the rightmost vertical line into the heap. Then we extract the top point from the heap, yield it and finally put its left neighbour into the heap (if it has one). So heap always contains at most len(l1) elements, and every new generated point cost us O(log(len(l1))). Solution can be improved if we choose l1 to be smallest list from two given.

Here is example solution:

```
import heapq

a = [("a", 6), ("b", 4), ("c", 3), ("d", 1)]
b = [("e", 5), ("f", 5), ("g", 4), ("h", 2)]

class Pair:
    def __init__(self, i, j, value):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.value = value
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return other.value - self.value

def solution(a, b):
    heap = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        heapq.heappush(heap, Pair(i, 0, a[i][1] + b[0][1]))
    while len(heap) > 0:
        pair = heapq.heappop(heap)
        yield (a[pair.i], b[pair.j], pair.value)
        if pair.j + 1 < len(b):
            heapq.heappush(heap, Pair(pair.i, pair.j + 1, a[pair.i][1] + b[pair.j + 1][1]))

for (a, b, value) in solution(a, b):
    print ("%s %s -> %d" % (a, b, value))
```

Things get worse when we are going into higher dimensions (more than 2 lists to combine). It can be solved on top of the 2D solution, with memoization, so we first build an answer for l1,l2 as lazy-list-like data structure, and then apply the same algorithm again, for this memoized list and l3 as arguments, and so on. One last step that must be taken - we should either always use array with smaller length as l1, or get rid of pushing all elements of l1 into heap in the beginning.

Complete code example for N lists [here](http://pastebin.com/xTJXT1Tv), as it too long.

Comment: Nice analysis and solution!  I was trying to define the problem as a complex DFS of a custom tree but I'll have a closer look at this first.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easily approachable with a simple greedy-style algorithm. That said, I'm assuming you have access to the specific values rather than just a sorted list of the values. Also assuming that it comes sorted.

```
l1 = [(a, 2), (b, 1), (c, 1)]
l2 = [(d, 2), (e, 2), (f, 1)]
```

The truth is it's pretty non-trivial, but here's how you can approach the problem (code will probably come later, because as I said, it's actually non-trivial.)

Assuming you have three possible actions at any given point:

1. (highest in next_values (see below), highest remaining entry of l2 for l1)
2. (Current entry of l1, next entry of l2) # Assumes you're iterating through l2
3. (Next entry of l1, highest remaining entry of l2)

Then you must simply keep track of the value of each of those three, over time and choose the optimal at each timestep. It's not entirely lazy as you have to update these three values at each timestep, it's pretty close.

To actually implement this there's one data structure we have to keep around:

```
next_entries: {*l1: last entry of l2 explored}
next_values: {*l1: l1 entry + next l2 entry}
```

At which point the calculations for the three possible points above can be done. Again, can produce code, will probably do, but it's probably ~20 dense lines to do in a good readable way.

Comment: This sounds like the right direction to me as well.  What if a copy where made of each list and the copies would only contain the highest non-exhausted value-set (ie. all the 2's in this example) for that specific list.  In this case it would mean l1 = [a] and l2 = [d,e].  All permutations would be generated for these lists and then the list with the next lowest non-null value-set would be popped and populated. (arbitrarily choosing l1 over l2 in this case, giving l1=[b,c] and l2 = [d,e].  Permutations would then be generated for the new l1 and l2 etc.

Comment: I don't really understand how this works... What is the "current entry of `l1`" if we're iterating over `l2`? Also, why do we only have 3 possible actions at each point?

Comment: @quasiverse I think the solution is a bit more complicated even than this.  Anyhow, my understanding is that the the current entry of ``l1`` is the head of the recursion / the current stable member.

Comment: @Colin That copying technique is relatively equivalent to the one I laid out, if slightly more storage-intensive. I imagine that approach would be better if the spread of values is relatively small compared to the number of values, but I think this would be more efficient if the spread is larger. Your understanding is accurate.

Comment: @quasiverse There are only three possible actions because we've assumed that the lists are sorted. The three options are basically: increment l1, increment l2, return to head. If the lists weren't sorted at the start this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus So my understanding is that: given we currently are at indexes `i1`, `i2` in `l1` and `l2` respectively, your algorithm says the next pair must have index in `l1` that is either `i1`, `i1+1`, or we go back to the lowest lowest index of `l1` that still has pairs left. Here is a case I don't understand. (new comment because of character limit)

Comment: Suppose the values in the lists are `l1 = (a,b,c) = (5,2,1)`, `l2 = (d,e,f) = (7,5,0)`. In this case the solution is `ad, ae, bd, cd, be, ce, af, bf, cf`. However when we are at `cd` (`i1 = 2` 0-indexed), the next best pair is `be` where `i1 = 1` which is not the lowest index with pairs left (which would be `i1 = 0` since we have not used `(i1, i2) =  (0, 2) = af`) and neither is it equal the previous `i1` or `i1+1`.

Comment: @quasiverse Thanks for pointing out that edge case, I made an assumption in my exploration that was honestly silly, small edit, but will make it now.